# How to unprotect Visio page using C#

Tags: c#, automation, visio

I have a password protected (.vsd) Visio drawing page, which contains several macros, which are the reasons for the page being protected.

How can I programmatically unprotect it using c#?

Comment: Since the answer is "you cannot do that" I think it might be okay to keep the question. Means what kind of efforts can we discuss, when it's just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot protect/unprotect a Visio drawing programmatically. Means, there is no such API available (for security reasons). The best you can do is SendKeys (i.e. UI automation).